# Cocoa Error 2048 on NSRegularExpression Creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to create regular expression from the following:

```
#define RegEX_1_UPPER_1_SPECIAL @"((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@!%*?&-+_()]).{8,})"

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: RegEX_1_UPPER_1_SPECIAL options:0 error:&error];
```

But, unfortunately it returns me the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0x7ff6f51b5af0 {NSInvalidValue=(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@!%*?&-+_]).{8,15}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the hyphen inside your collection of special characters. The hyphen has a special meaning within the `[` and `]`, namely a range of characters (e.g. `[A-Z]`). If you want to search for a literal hyphen, you have to escape that:

```
#define RegEX_1_UPPER_1_SPECIAL @"((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@!%*?&\\-+_()]).{8,})"
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.It Worked like a charm. Again you proved veteran :)

Comment: @Jerrin - In the future, please post your own question rather than posting comments to other questions. That’s why the moderator deleted your prior comment. In answer to your question, you want `@"[>\\[]Read ..."`. That will match `>Read` and `]Read`. Note the `[` inside `[` and `]` needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Rob  i will do that, since its the same error just a different expression I thought commenting was enough.

Comment: @Jerrin - Regex is so dependent upon the individual details of exactly what you’re looking for, that each likely deserves its own question, with links back to other answers that you’ve investigated, so you don’t get down-votes for insufficient research. (But just imagine if every regex error was buried as comments under this answer; it would be a nightmare. lol.)